# C# Socket using BinaryReader/Writer is getting the wrong data from reader

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I am working on a project for class and I have to create a socket server and then a bunch of fake clients that request tickets from a queue. I have all that working just fine however, when I read my Ticket object from the Socket stream I only ever get the first object sent.

At the line `Console.WriteLine($"ID {paramData.ClientID} got ticket {tick.TicketID} for show {tick.EventName}");` I get my unique client id which is generated during the for loop however, I get the ticket id of 0 every time.

I have a few thoughts but I am just not sure why this is happening. Firstly, the sends the first ticket over the socket and then re-uses that ticket every time but I am not sure why that would happen, because I dequeue one before sending it.

Another thought is I am just doing the threading completely wrong but I don't understand how the same ticket shows up on the different threads.

Here is a screenshot of the executed code with 10 purchase attempts and 5 available tickets
[image]

Entire Code:

```
class Program
{
    static ConcurrentQueue<Ticket> _TicketStorage = new ConcurrentQueue<Ticket>();
    static Socket ServerSocket;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Server ...");

        // Gets the event name to apply to all the tickets
        Console.Write("Enter Name of Event: ");
        var eventName = Console.ReadLine();

        // Allows the user to set the ticket count or defaults to 500
        Console.Write("\nEnter Max Number of Tickets (Default: 500): ");
        var ticketCountTry = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int TicketCountResult);

        // Setups up the ticket q
        Console.WriteLine("Initilizing Ticket Storage");
        for (int i = 0; i < (ticketCountTry ? TicketCountResult : 5); i++)
        {
            _TicketStorage.Enqueue(new Ticket(eventName, i));
        }

        Console.Clear();

        // Finish line for application
        Console.WriteLine("Server is ready to process requests");

        var ServerThread = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> 
        {
            StartServerListener();
        },TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        StartFakeClients();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void StartFakeClients()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter number of tickets to attempt to purchase (Default: 600): ");
        var attemptNumberTry = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int attemptAmount);

        // Setup all the connections to be in the ready state
        for (int i = 0; i < (attemptNumberTry ? attemptAmount : 10); i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FakeClientWorker, new
            {
                ClientID = i
            });

            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        }
    }

    static void FakeClientWorker(object state)
    {
        dynamic paramData = state;

        // Create a connection to the server
        var Connection = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Connection.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 11000);


        using (var bReader = new BinaryReader(new NetworkStream(Connection, true), Encoding.UTF8, false))
        {
            // Create my high level reader to parse incoming data
            var dataBlock = bReader.ReadString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataBlock))
            {
                Ticket tick = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ticket>(dataBlock);
                Console.WriteLine($"ID {paramData.ClientID} got ticket {tick.TicketID} for show {tick.EventName}");
            }
            else
            {
                // Didn't get a ticket
                Console.WriteLine($"ID {paramData.ClientID} didn't get a ticket");
            }
        }
    }

    static void StartServerListener()
    {
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);

        ServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        ServerSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
        ServerSocket.Listen(100);

        while (true)
        {
            var clientSocket = ServerSocket.Accept();

            // You just got a new client asking for a ticket
            // Send this connection to another thread and then continue listening for connections
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoServerWork, clientSocket);
        }
    }

    static void DoServerWork(object clientSocket)
    {
        // Get the next ticket from the q
        var hasNewTickets = _TicketStorage.TryDequeue(out Ticket EventTicket);

        // Start a writer
        var n = new NetworkStream((Socket)clientSocket, false);
        using (var bWriter = new BinaryWriter(new NetworkStream((Socket)clientSocket, true), Encoding.UTF8, false))
        {
            // I have my writer now I need to send this data
            bWriter.Write((hasNewTickets ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(EventTicket) : String.Empty));
        } // Dispose of the advanced network stream, Dispose of the binary writer, close the connection
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A structure for storing information about an event
/// </summary>
public class Ticket
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique identifer for the ticket 
    /// </summary>
    public readonly int TicketID;

    /// <summary>
    /// Event name this ticket represents
    /// </summary>
    public readonly String EventName;

    public Ticket(String EventName, int ID)
    {
        this.EventName = EventName;
        TicketID = ID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive, this is not a *"BinaryReader/Writer issue"*. You are using `JsonConvert`(from [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) I think) for serialization and deserialization of your object. I think if you debug your project, you can find that `dataBlock` passed to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ticket>()` method is just fine.

The true reason is that your `Ticket` class has no default constructor. In this case, `JsonConvert` will try to match constructor parameters names with values from JSON. That's why you get correct `EventName`, but default `TicketID` (0). Try to change your constructor to this:

```
public Ticket(String EventName, int TicketID)
{
    this.EventName = EventName;
    this.TicketID = TicketID;
}
```

Comment: Wow I hate the internet for today. I am sitting here stressing about how to properly do this assignment and something simple like my data serialization was the true problem..